# Search Within Capture Group RegEx Beginner

Tags: regex

Really simple question that I'm sure exists, I just can't find it on google.

Say I have this document:

```
Class of 2010
My favorite number 2012
123213 123123 ajehfga;hg;
```

I want to capture the 2010 so i would say:

```
Class of \d\d\d\d
```

But then I want to get rid of the 'Class of '. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the `\d`s into a capturing group:

```
Class of (\d\d\d\d)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN8qT7/1) (note that in most cases you can just use a limiting quantifier `{n}`: `Class of (\d{4})`). This is a more or less universal mechanism and approach to getting subpattern submatches with regex.

Another alternative is a positive look-behind:

```
(?<=Class of )\d\d\d\d
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN8qT7/2)

However, a look-behind is costly in terms of effeciency.

Answer (score 0):

Class of 2010 : `/class of (\d{4})/i`

My favorite number 2012 : `/My favorite number (\d{4})/i`

123213 123123 ajehfga;hg; : `/(\d+)/`

In php you'd do:

```
$matches = array();
if(preg_match('/class of (\d{4})/i', $haystack, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

In javascript you'd do:

```
var year = haystack.match(/class of (\d{4})/i)[1];
```